# How to read ECB data using CURL_init()

Tags: php, xml, curl, currency

Guys please help me I am a little stuck here. 
The code below is not returning any results.. !!
I am not able to understand where I am going wrong?

```
private function _request($url)
{
    $url="https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";

    if (function_exists('curl_version'))
    {

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);

        $raw_data = $this->_curl_exec_follow($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    } else // no CUrl, try differently
        $raw_data = file_get_contents($url);

    print_r("------------<br>");
    print_r($raw_data);
    print_r("<br>------------"); exit();


}
```

Comment: It helps the visibility of your question if you add the language you are using as a tag.

Comment: I am using php language